# XMLHTTP - How to get info FROM Ajax after 5 seconds with Server.XMLHTTP ?? Impossible?

Tags: xml, ajax, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

How to capture information from another site that uses Ajax?? This site puts information 5 seconds after entering on the page. I'm using Server.XMLHTTP. And only can get the main page (full page) whitout the ajax inside a span . Is possible to create a delay to wait this 5 seconds and get information from this span ?? I'm using ASP, like this:

```
url = "http://www.test.com" 

objXMLHttp.Open "GET", Url, False

objXMLHttp.Send

strURL = BinaryToString(objXmlHttp.ResponseBody)

response.write strURL
```

You can enter: http://es.groupalia.com/descuentos-barcelona/escapada-esqui-forfait-sort.html and see the Source Code. See if you can get information inside the span `id=texto_compradores` . I would like to get how many byers from a site (collective buying website). I can get this info from others sites that doesn't use ajax to refresh this info.

Comment: Do you want to get AJAX generated data in the page? If yes, its not possible by a direct access, since it doesn't process javascript.

Comment: do you know how the ajax request looks like? you could send the ajax request directly from your asp. then it is of course not an ajax but a serverside xmlhttp request

Comment: The question whilst containing a reasonable amount of text is actually quite difficult to decipher.  Please explain more explicitly the steps you need from the your clients Browser until the desired result.

Comment: I think that question is quite simple. How can I get the total of buyers from a collective buying website using an automatically script ? I have one using server.xmlhttp and I can get this info from site that doesn't use ajax to refresh this info, like groupon, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the total amount of coupons is the info you need, you'll have to do 2 calls, *or* deduce the ID info of the product before making the call:

1. You have to get the page as you're getting it right now
2. Locate the **product ID**, the **STORE** and the **URL** from this line of the source code you get:

   var data0 = {"product_id": "31031", "store": " barcelona_es", "url" : "/descuentos-barcelona/escapada-esqui-forfait-sort.html"};
3. Make a post call to: **http://es.groupalia.com/live/descuentos-barcelona/ajax/getProductInfo/**  with the parameters **product ID**, **STORE** and **URL** you got.  You will get a bunch of numbers.
4. Each group of coupons will be separated with **#**.  Iterate through the result by splitting by #, for each one you'll have to split by **;**, the last item of this split array is the total coupon number

---

You cannot get the result of an AJAX call by calling directly from server and getting the page because this loads AFTER the page has loaded.  So, you'll need make 2 calls.

Use the javascript function **procesa_resp(data)** on the groupalia page to know how the pare that bunch of numbers you get from the page.

Hope it helps!!!